# Filepath of unuploaded file

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

How can I get the absolute filepath of a file without uploaded it on the server ?

I need to record this filepath in a database so an other program can read the database, get this filepath and then read the file.

Comment: The webbrowsers prevent you to read this information, in the name of security....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons this information is not available in JavaScript and that's why not in Vaadin either.